# SPF record seems to not register at gmail (at least)

Tags: dns, spf

So I have the following SPF record for the domain hojio.com:

The TXT records found for your domain are:

> v=spf1 ip4:194.150.114.22 ip4:194.150.114.0/24
>   include:support.zendesk.com include:smtp.zendesk.com ~all

The domain is on the ip 194.150.114.22 and a reverse dns lookup on that ip gives hojio.com

Gmail says:

> neutral (google.com: 194.150.114.22 is neither permitted nor denied by
>   best guess record for domain of www-data@ksenikovweb01.dandomain.net)
>   client-ip=194.150.114.22;

As if its not finding any SPF record? This is strange, since I can use various online SPF record checker tools, that all give me the correct one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that hojio.com is being used in the Return-Path?  SPF works off the Return-Path, not the From address.  So it doesn't matter if the From address is from a user at `hojio.com`, unless the Return-Path is the same.

From the Gmail message it looks like the Return-Path is `www-data@ksenikovweb01.dandomain.net`.  The domain `ksenikovweb01.dandomain.net` does not have an SPF record, so that would explain the 'neutral' SPF rating.